# Unable to determine if app installed after upgrading build compileSdkVersion to 30

Tags: android

We have the following code to determine if Facebook, Twitter etc. is installed on the app (for simplicity code posted is refactored for just Facebook).

```
        String packageName = "com.facebook.katana";
        info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
        if(info != null && info.applicationInfo.enabled) {
            LogTool.c(TAG, platform.name() + " is installed");
            return true;
        }
```

This code works as expected until we upgraded the build.gradle file to `compileSdkVersion 30` and `targetSdkVersion 30`. When these were both at 29 they worked as expected. Upgrading to version 30 give the following error:

```
class android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException
```

Anyone know what the correct way, or what I'm missing, to do this with the latest versions of these apps?

Comment: Are you testing this on Android 11? If so, did you [add a `<queries>` element to your manifest](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility)?

Comment: Check the [docs for queries in android 11](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility)

Comment: Adding the <queries> for the given apps did the trick, if either of you would like to post the answer I will be glad to accept it.